# Creating Php function to return css class

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, oop

In my wordpress template I am changing div class according to wordpress option setting values. I have multiple template /pages , so instead of repeating the php code on each template page, I want to create a function to return variable css class( `$div` here).

Wordpress option setting gives 2 variables: `$pagewidth` & `$pagecolor`.

**PHP:**

```
 <?php
    $pagewidth = 'big'; //big,small or tinny
    $pagecolor =  'white'; //white or black

    $divclass = array();
    $divclass = array($pagewidth,$pagecolor );
    $div = $divclass['0'].'-'.divclass['1'].'-box';
?>
```

**css:**

```
.big-white-box{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(images/big-white.png) repeat;}

.big-black-box{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(images/big-black.png) repeat;}

.small-white-box{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(images/small-white.png) repeat;}

.small-black-box{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(images/small-black.png) repeat;}

.tinny-white-box{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(images/tinny-white.png) repeat;}

.tinny-black-box{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(images/tinny-black.png) repeat;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="<?php echo $div; ?>" >


<!--content-goes-here--->
</div>
```

Help me to create a php function which return css variable `$div`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with oop ... anyways, whats the problem?

Comment: i see `width:10o%;` in your code and not `width:100%;` make sure you correct it in your css

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake in my question ,its 100% in my actual code.

Comment: I have more than 30 pages, so writing same php code in each page is not a good practice .Thats why i want to achieve this using few line of codes.

Answer (score 1):

Havnt test it but something like this?

```
function getTemp( $WPtemplate , $pagewidth, $pagecolor ){
    $divclass = array();
    if( $WPtemplate == 1 ){
        $divclass = array($pagewidth,$pagecolor );
        $div = $divclass['0'].'-'.$divclass['1'].'-box';
        return $div;
    }
}
```